# Reuse code between React.js and React Native applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to reuse some code that retrieves data from an API for two apps. One is an iOS app using React Native. The other one is a website using React.js.

I initially coded the class that retrieves data from an API when I built the iOS app. Thus, I used the `fetch` method available in React Native.

Unfortunately, there isn't such a method in React.js. 
My best option if I want to reuse my code is to abstract the call of the React Native's `fetch` method by creating a class `HTTPRequests` with a method `fetch` which will call the React Native's `fetch` method or the '$.get' method depending on the lib used by the project: React.js or React Native.

My question is the following: How can I detect the using of React.js or React Native in my project. My first idea is to detect if my JS code is executed through `RCTRootView` engine or a browser. But I've no idea how to accomplish this.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: There are libraries that implement the fetch API in a browser, for example: https://github.com/github/fetch .

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to move shared logic into separate module (bower, npm, ES6), generalize the way you request data through fetch polyfill, and never ever bother with detecting React/React.native in your project. JS code detection will make your code unnecessary complicated and hard to support when new versions of React/React.native will come up.

Comment: Yes you're right. I finally managed to not have to create two cases depending which library I'm using.

Comment: I'm curious on how you created the shared files? You use browserify?

Comment: @AndyB my rule of thumb would be a separate npm package, you could even use local dependencies https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths in your package.json with npm 2.0, I would also suggest linklocal package for development usage

Comment: @EugeneSafronov, cheers!! I won't have any problems with the exports in the browser? I.e. module.exports = MyModuleName;

Comment: @AndyB in the browser you will need either browserify or webpack. They both understands node's export style or modules API (with use of babel)

Comment: @EugeneSafronov, brilliant thanks!! I'll need to read up on how to use them. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have successful experience of building a cross-platform application with React and React Native using the [platform-specific extensions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#platform-specific-extensions) feature of React Native. I've just described how I structured the code in order to achieve that in a blog post [Code sharing between React and React Native applications](http://ihor.burlachenko.com/code-sharing-between-react-and-react-native-applications/)